# Is moving fast will effect WiFi transceiving beavior?

Tags: wireless, wifi, speed

Let's say I'm driving a [2010 Bugatti Veyron 16.4 Super Sport](http://www.topcarrating.com/2010-bugatti-veyron-16-4-super-sport.php), with speed of 
431 km/h = 268 m/h = 119 m/s

Now I have a WiFi signal receiver installed on the top of the car and a WiFi transmitter in a fixed base station.
[An access point in a fixed station that covers area of 4km , and a WiFi receiver with high power]

- Will moving this fast effects receiving the signal ?
- What are the parameters to calculate the possible drop in signal
  receiving ?
- Will any packets get dropped when moving this fast ?
- Is it the same situation for transmitting from the car to the station
  ?

What I found till now that [Doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) may effect , but I don't know how.

Update#1: 
[Wi-Fi in high-speed transport communications](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1109%2Fitst.2009.5399314)

Comment: 119m/s? That's it?

Comment: It reminds me of the anecdote about the Doppler Effect and the traffic light..

Comment: Thsi sounds like ep1 of Scorpion where they wanted to tap the wifi signal from a moving plane.

Comment: In fact Doppler effect can actually have an impact. For example, GSM phones hardware has facilities to compensate for it. [this may be useful](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-to-estimate-and-compensate-for-doppler-shift-in-wireless-signals).

Comment: If the speed toward or away from the transmitter is 119 m/s, the Doppler shift will be almost 1 kHz for 2.5 GHz Wif. And almost 2 kHz for 5 GHz Wifi. I do not know how much of a problem that might be.

Comment: This is great to know that Doppler effect will do something, but

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At a speed of 119 m/s and a frequency of 2.45 GHz, the doppler shift will be 971 Hz. See [this](https://www.easycalculation.com/physics/classical-physics/doppler-effect-approaching-receiver.php) on-line calculator.

That is what a receiver may have to cope with. If you then consider the accuracy of the crystal oscillators at either end of a radio link, the frequency differences are likely to be in the realms of hundreds of hertz BUT the receiver copes.

The receiver copes by tracking the signal it is trying to receive with several methods but ultimately it boils down to a phase locked loop (PLL) adjusting a voltage controlled oscillator (VCO) to keep absolutely spot-on in sync while decoding data.

I'm going have a stab at a guesstimate that several kHz of clock difference can be tolerated using this method. If there is a mechanism that can take account of clock differences then it will take account of doppler shifts too. The only thing to really shake this theory is really extreme accelerations because the "system" will have a small time lag and it might just get out of sync for a few moments and of course reception of a packet may be jeopardized and that packet may require to be retransmitted.

I recently watched a programme on TV about the sad loss of Malaysian Airlines flight MH370 - the system that was used to receive the hourly automated transmissions also "held" values of control voltages used to tweak shifts in transmit and receive frequencies and these numbers held all the information about doppler shifts too. In effect they were able to tell what direction the plane was flying and pin-point a crash area of about 100 sq miles. I was amazed that the "tweak" parameters were held in a data base and that this information was available retrospectively.

The slow moving (or static) "value" offset would represent the almost fixed difference in frequency between the tx and rx oscillators whilst the more dynamic changes would be the doppler shift effect. See [this](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/24/malaysian-airliners-path-ultimately-tracked-by-satellite-pings-doppler-shift/) article about the doppler method used.

Ultimately, what I'm labouring to say is that doppler effect is likely to be "fixed" by the same mechanism that fixes the difference between clock frequencies at either end of the link.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks a lot , does it happen you know any wifi access point that handles this problem automatically ?

Comment: I believe that all radio data comm systems must have some form of VCO auto-tune/lock facility or they just won't work very well and not be able to support complex modulation methods. This includes wifi naturally but, I can't recommend one because I've never had to put one to the test. I have designed my own FM data transmitters used on high-rpm machines for picking off data but the specifications on bandwidth were lenient. However, the PLL/VCO control loop did have to act quite fast because doppler was happening at up to 3000 per second!

Comment: Wow ! .... 
is your design open source ? it may benefit me some how

Comment: Unfortunately not and it is only a very short range (12") very low power system.

Comment: Great, if you where in my place , what should I do next ?

Comment: Start up the Bugatti, of course.

Answer (score 2):

My answer relies on my experience in multiple generations of Wifi systems design (802.11g/a/n/ac).

The Doppler calculation in the previous post is correct.

Wifi receivers deal with crystals with an accuracy of about 20ppm (20 parts per million). This means a receiver and a transmitter can have a difference of 40ppm between them, because one can be shifting up while the other is shifting down. 
If you compute the frequency difference such a clock drift generates at 2400MHz it is 2400e6*40e-6 = 96KHz. Far greater than the Doppler shift mentioned. Therefore, there shouldn't be a problem from a frequency tracking perspective.

Furthermore, the ability to discern the frequency shift is limited by the specification (frequency estimation ambiguity point) at 625kHk, again, no problem here.

Regarding path loss... If you are taking the a 4km distance of free space, the loss is (based on the Friis equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation), neglecting antenna gains.

PL [dB] = 32.5 + 20*log10(F*R), where F is the frequency in Ghz and R is the distance in Km

32.5+20*log10(2.4*4) ~ 52.5 dB.

A Wifi transmitter can transmit at about 16-30dBm. Taking even the low range of 16dBm, the signal will reach the receiver at 16-52.5 = -36.5dBm. This is a very high signal for Wifi systems. Their sensitivity for OFDM is in the range of -90 to -70 dBm. Therefore, the signal strength poses no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Frequency tracking is not really the issue when considering the Doppler effects on WiFi OFDM signals. While it is true that WiFi receivers can tolerate 20ppm frequency error in reference crystals, it is important to realize that the frequency error is somewhat "fixed" relative to 1/(symbol time) and changes very slowly with temperature and aging. Doppler has no real impact here.
It is the actual symbols which are phase related that need consideration. 802.11ac/a/n/g OFDM signals use QAM modulation on each tone. QAM is quadrature amplitude modulation. Each rate can only tolerate a certain amount of phase or amplitude error usually quantified as error vector magnitude or EVM. Each symbol is about 4uS in duration, so any errors in phase or amplitude during that symbol period will result in a degraded EVM and if too large, then that symbol set is lost which could cause a packet loss. 
The calculations for Doppler shift effects should include the symbol time and the bandwidth of phase tracking, not frequency tracking of the system. A shift in phase is not necessarily a shift in frequency, but a shift in frequency is definitely a shift in phase.
It should also be noted that most WiFi APs don't have 4km of range, so at this speed, the car could be out of range before the association is completed.

Comment: Use 2 x <Enter> for paragraph breaks. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to register to correct the others. They weren't making any sense in my mind, yours was the answer I was looking for.