# What is the maximum relative speed at which wireless protocols can operate? (Doppler shift)

Tags: rf, wireless, wifi, satellite

Let's take Wi-Fi and UWB. What determines in these standards their robustness to Doppler shift? The most obvious is the range of carrier frequency tolerance. But in both standards this range is sufficient even if the relative speed is comparable to the orbital speeds (several km/s). [Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166602/is-moving-fast-will-effect-wifi-transceiving-beavior) it is mentioned thar for Wi-Fi can be as high as 96 kHz.
However, this is supposedly not the only and not the most important factor for a communication system. In a course on cellular communication systems, the following equation was mentioned:
$$
T_\text{frame} = \frac{c}{V_\text{max} \cdot F_{c}},
$$
where

- \$T_\text{frame}\$ is frame duration,
- \$c\$ - speed of light,
- \$ V_\text{max}\$ - maximum relative speed between base station and caller,
- \$ F_{c}\$ - carrier frequency

For UWB the standart IEEE 802.15.4 doesn't explicitly defines the maximum relative speed speed, but [datasheet for DW1000](https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da007946) does and it's 500 m/s for specified data rate and packet size. If we calculate the frame length for such input data and calculate the maximum frame length using the formula above, we get values of approximately the same order of magnitude.

So, my questions are:

- Is this formula accurate?
- What is maximum relative velocity for Wi-Fi devices?
- Are Wi-Fi and UWB even feasible protocols for earth-space communication? Like relative speeds of about 2-3 km/s? Not regarding path loss, only from doppler perspective

Comment: \$T_{FRAME}\$ becomes infinity when the relative speed is zero <-- does that make any sense to you (it doesn't to me).

Comment: Of course, that's the maximum length. So if we are stationary, frame lenght can be very long

Comment: Doppler shift is significant to LTE even at the speeds some trains travel:  https://www.sequans.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Sequans_High-Speed-LTE_Whitepaper_Final_071318.pdf